# LWC Dynamically Show a field based on picklist value

Tags: lightning-web-components, dynamic-binding

Based on the Subtopic__c or SubSubtopic__c (I know great API names) I want to show a text box called Other. I have looked at some documentation and based on what that has stated this should work. Take a look please and let me know what I did wrong.

HTML:

```
<template>
    <lightning-record-edit-form record-id="5000h00001e3oJpAAI"
    object-api-name="Case">
        <div class="slds-grid slds-gutters">
            <div class="slds-col">
                <lightning-input-field field-name="Topic__c" required>
                </lightning-input-field>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-col">
                <lightning-input-field field-name="Subtopic__c" required onchange={handleEvent}>
                </lightning-input-field>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-col">
                <lightning-input-field field-name="SubSubtopic__c" required onchange={handleEvent}>
                </lightning-input-field>
            </div>
        </div>
        <template if:true={areDetailsVisible}>
            <lightning-input-field id="other" field-name="Other__c">
            </lightning-input-field>
        </template>
        <div>
            <lightning-input-field field-name="Subject" required>
            </lightning-input-field>
        </div>
        <div>
            <lightning-input-field field-name="Description" required>
            </lightning-input-field>
        </div>
        <lightning-button
        class="slds-m-top_small"
        variant="brand"
        type="submit"
        name="update"
        label="Update">
        </lightning-button>
    </lightning-record-edit-form>
</template>
```

JS:

```
export default class EditCaseForm extends LightningElement {
    areDetailsVisible = false;

    handleEvent(event) {
        console.log(event.detail.value, ' SELECTED');
        if (event.detail.value = 'Other') {
            this.areDetailsVisible = true;
            console.log(event.detail.value, ' TRUE');
        } else {
            this.areDetailsVisible = false;
            console.log(event.detail.value, ' FALSE');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can use the below-working code as a reference where the rendering
>   of contact Phone field is dependent on the picklist values from Lead
>   Source and Level__c.That's where getters come into play.

```
<div class="slds-m-bottom_x-large">
        <h2 style="font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: red;">Custom Error mesage Record Edit Form Using Validation Rule And conditional rendering of fields</h2>
        <lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="Contact">
            <lightning-messages>
            </lightning-messages>
            <lightning-input-field field-name="Name">
            </lightning-input-field>
            <lightning-input-field field-name="Email">
            </lightning-input-field>
            <lightning-input-field field-name="Level__c" onchange={handleLevelEvent}>
            </lightning-input-field>
            <lightning-input-field field-name="LeadSource" onchange={handleSourceEvent}>
            </lightning-input-field>
            <template if:true={renderOptionalField}>
                <lightning-input-field field-name="Phone">
                </lightning-input-field>
            </template>
            <lightning-button class="slds-m-top_small" type="submit" label="Create new">
            </lightning-button>
        </lightning-record-edit-form>
    </div>



get renderOptionalField() {
        return this.level === 'Primary' && this.leadSource === 'Web' ? true : false;
    }
```

> Only when Level__c value is Primary and LeadSource is web then the
>   Optional field is visible.

```
handleLevelEvent(event) {
    this.level = event.target.value;
}
handleSourceEvent(event) {
    this.leadSource = event.target.value;
}
```

[image: Demo]

Comment: So can you elaborate on how you are getting this.level and this.leadSource?

Comment: The question comes from when loading the page the conditional field doesn't load since the onchange hasn't fired. So any ideas on that would be helpful.

Comment: level and lead source values come based on user input , once both the criteria are met the field becomes visible due to the getter used.

Comment: Have you ever figured out how to get the data that is loaded in the form to do a show/hide a field? I have the code working as if the user inputs but not when the page is loaded and the field is already set to that value.

Answer (score 1):

You are using an expression instead of a comparison in the if statement.
it should be 
`if(event.detail.value === 'Other'){
  //if block
}
else{
 //else block
}`

If this is not the case, please post your error messages if you see any.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I was trusting that Ssalesforce made the development server actually work. The main problem was that the development server doesn't allow reactive components.