# LWC Show a field OnLoad based on a dependant picklist

Tags: lightning-web-components

So I have a form that has 4 dependent picklists where 3 of them could have the value 'Other' which if either one of them has that value that will show a text box for the user to enter in a value. I have this functionality working only IF the user is making the selections. The part I don't have working is later on when they come back and the form reloads and if one of the 3 picklists have 'Other' selection, the text box doesn't show. I have played around with the onLoad event but can't seem to get this working.

HTML

```
<template>
    <template if:true={showSpinner}>
        <lightning-spinner alternative-text="Saving" size="medium"></lightning-spinner>
    </template>
    <lightning-record-edit-form record-id={recordId}
    record-type-id={recordTypeId}
    object-api-name="Case"
    onsuccess={handleSuccess}
    onload={handleOnLoad}
    density="comfy">
        <lightning-messages>
        </lightning-messages>
        <div class="slds-grid slds-gutters">
            <div class="slds-col" style="width:100%">
                <lightning-input-field field-name="AccountId" required>
                </lightning-input-field>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-col" style="width:100%">
                <lightning-input-field field-name="AssetId" required>
                </lightning-input-field>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-grid slds-gutters">
            <div class="slds-col" style="width:100%">
                <lightning-input-field field-name="ContactId" required>
                </lightning-input-field>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-col" style="width:100%">
                <lightning-input-field field-name="Origin" required>
                </lightning-input-field>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-grid slds-gutters">
            <div class="slds-col" style="width:100%">
                <lightning-input-field field-name="Status" required>
                </lightning-input-field>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-col" style="width:100%">
                <lightning-input-field field-name="Type" required>
                </lightning-input-field>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-grid slds-gutters">
            <div class="slds-col" style="width:100%">
                <lightning-input-field field-name="Topic__c" required>
                </lightning-input-field>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-col" style="width:100%">
                <lightning-input-field field-name="Subtopic__c" required onchange={handleEvent} onload={handleOnLoad}>
                </lightning-input-field>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-col" style="width:100%">
                <lightning-input-field field-name="SubSubtopic__c" required onchange={handleEvent1} onload={handleOnLoad}>
                </lightning-input-field>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-col" style="width:100%">
                <lightning-input-field field-name="Sub_Sub_Category__c" required onchange={handleEvent2} onload={handleOnLoad}>
                </lightning-input-field>
            </div>
        </div>
        <template if:true={areDetailsVisible}>
            <lightning-input-field id="other" field-name="Other__c" required>
            </lightning-input-field>
        </template>
        <div>
            <lightning-input-field field-name="Subject" required>
            </lightning-input-field>
        </div>
        <div>
            <lightning-input-field field-name="Description" required>
            </lightning-input-field>
        </div>
        <lightning-button
        class="slds-m-top_small"
        variant="brand"
        type="submit"
        name="update"
        label="Update Case"
        onerror={handleFail}
        onclick={handleLoading}
        onsuccess={handleSuccess}>
        </lightning-button>
    </lightning-record-edit-form>
</template>
```

JS

```
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import { FlowNavigationNextEvent } from 'lightning/flowSupport';

export default class EditCaseForm extends LightningElement {
    areDetailsVisible = false;
    showSpinner = false;
    @api recordId;
    @api recordTypeId;
    @api availableActions = [];

    @api
    handleGoNext() {
        if (this.availableActions.find(action => action === 'NEXT')) {
            // navigate to the next screen
            const navigateNextEvent = new FlowNavigationNextEvent();
            this.dispatchEvent(navigateNextEvent);
        }
    }

    handleEvent(event) {
    if (event.detail.value === 'Other') {
            this.areDetailsVisible = true;
        } else {
            this.areDetailsVisible = false;
        }
    }

    handleEvent1(event) {
    if (event.detail.value === 'Other') {
            this.areDetailsVisible = true;
        } else {
            this.areDetailsVisible = false;
        }
    }

    handleEvent2(event) {
    if (event.detail.value === 'Other') {
            this.areDetailsVisible = true;
        } else {
            this.areDetailsVisible = false;
        }
    }

    handleSuccess(event) {
        this.showNotification();
        this.showSpinner = false;
        this.handleGoNext();
        return { isValid: true };
    }

    handleOnLoad(event) {

    }

    handleLoading() {
        this.showSpinner = true;
    }

    handleFail() {
        this.showSpinner = false;
    }

    showNotification() {
        const evt = new ShowToastEvent({
            title: "Successfully Updated Case",
            message: "This case has been updated",
            variant: "success",
            mode: "pester"
        });
        this.dispatchEvent(evt);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have played with the onLoad and getting the details of the record that came back and I got to the RecordId but I could not get to the fields. I ended up doing a @wire and getting the fields through a query and then creating an IF statement to check each one of the fields. This is working as I want this to do so now.

If anyone still knows how to get the onLoad with data parameter and all the record information as this document is stating that can be done that would be very helpful and I think a much cleaner solution.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-record-edit-form/documentation

JS

```
    @wire(getRecord, {recordId: '$recordId', fields: [Department, Category, SubCategory, SubSubCategory] })
    record;

    showOtherTextBox() {
        console.log('DATA!!! ', JSON.stringify(this.record.data));
        if (this.record.data.fields.Topic__c.value === 'Other' || 
        this.record.data.fields.Subtopic__c.value === 'Other' || 
        this.record.data.fields.SubSubtopic__c.value === 'Other' || 
        this.record.data.fields.Sub_Sub_Category__c.value === 'Other') {
            this.areDetailsVisible = true
        } else {
            this.areDetailsVisible = false;
        }
    }

    handleOnLoad(event) {
        this.showOtherTextBox();
    }
```

Comment: I have answered a similar scenario here.You can try this.https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/297008/lwc-dynamically-show-a-field-based-on-picklist-value/297062#297062

Comment: You answered the onChange handling, but not the onLoad handling. This question covers the onLoad handling